# Oracle SQL comparison of DATEs returns wrong result

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, where-clause

I have `REPORTDATE` column in database (`DATETIME`) type.
I want to extract only `DATE` value from the DATETIME, then to do `COUNT` for each day and to put `WHERE` clause to restrict only dates later than some specific date.

So I have this clause:

```
SELECT to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS MY, COUNT(*) from INCIDENT
where to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')>'09.11.2013'

GROUP BY to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

It returns me results but but I can notice wrong result such as : `30.10.2013` which is wrong result.

How to solve this?

Comment: to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')>'09.11.2013'. How do you expect it to compare when you convert it to char?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> WHERE to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')>'09.11.2013'

You are comparing two **STRINGS**. You need to compare the **DATE**s. As I already said in the other answer here, you need to leave the date as it is for DATE calculations. **TO_CHAR** is for display, and **TO_DATE** is to convert a string literal into DATE.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
  COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE REPORTDATE > TO_DATE('09.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Also, REPORTDATE is a DATE column, hence it will have datetime element. So, if you want to exclude the time element while comparing, you need to use **TRUNC**

```
WHERE TRUNC(REPORTDATE) > TO_DATE('09.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

However, applying **TRUNC** on the date **column** would suppress any regular **index** on that column. From performance point of view, better use a **Date range condition**.

For example,

```
WHERE REPORTDATE
BETWEEN 
        TO_DATE('09.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
AND     
        TO_DATE('09.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY') +1
```

Comment: @Dejan, You need ot put the TRUNC over the column as I have shown in the end.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B - Regarding this part of your answer: "You are comparing two STRINGS. You need to compare the DATEs":  I think it's worth pointing out that the reason the OP's original query didn't work is *not* due to the use of string comparison instead of date comparison. It's due to the *way* they did the string comparison.  If they had used to_char(REPORTDATE, 'YYYY.MM.DD')>'2013.09.11', then the query would have worked.

Comment: @dcp, it is like saying `'a' > 'b'`

Comment: @Latif Kumar B - Not sure I understand your comment.  'a' is actually less than 'b'.  My point was that the query wasn't wrong because he was comparing strings instead of dates, it was how he was comparing the strings that was incorrect. However, your answer seems to indicate that you must use date comparisons to get the query to work correctly, which is incorrect.

Comment: Seems like you did not understand what I said. It might just get working for your specific NLS_* settings, it may not work on other clients or servers. That is why an explicit date format is important. It is always, I will repeat always important to explicitly transform your string into a date using the built-in to_date function. Have a look at this similar question stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql

Comment: `Also, REPORTDATE is a DATE column, hence it will have datetime element. So, if you want to exclude the time element while comparing, you need to use TRUNC` That is not a good idea unless there is a function-based index on the column. There are better ways of doing this without resorting to `TRUNC()`.

Comment: @Latitu Kumar B - NLS_DATE_FORMAT doesn't come into play here, because the mask passed to to_char is  YYYY.MM.DD, which uses all numbers. So unless I'm missing something, to_char(REPORTDATE, 'YYYY.MM.DD')  will always produce the same output regardless of any NLS settings. If you have an example where that would not be the case, then feel free to post it.  I do agree with you that it's best to compare dates to dates when possible.

Comment: @DavidFaber I agree regarding functuon-based index here. A regular index would be ignored if a function is applied. But that is not the main answer to the question. I just mentioned it to OP since he is comparing dates, and with only date element. I can't go deeper into explaining about function-based index in the answer, since it would be out if scope of the current question.

Comment: @DavidFaber I added that part now.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')>'09.11.2013'` compare to strings, so `30.10.2013` is after `09.11.2013`.
You need to compare the dates, not the string values, so you have to change your query to the following.

```
SELECT to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS MY, COUNT(1) 
from INCIDENT
where trunc(REPORTDATE)> to_date('09.11.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
GROUP BY to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

**Note:** I added a little modification from `count(*)` to `count(1)` for optimize the query having the same results.

Comment: `COUNT(1)` doesn't offer anything over `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: COUNT(*) check if any of the columns has a value not null. COUNT(1) doesn't check single columns. It return the number of rows, not the number of rows with at least one field not null.

Comment: `COUNT(*) check if any of the columns has a value not null` - What is the basis for this statement? Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Count(*) and Count(1) are the same in all aspects. Unless you are on primitive release where it used to be some difference. There has had been numerous discussions on this in the past. Just google it and see. The best answer by the master Thomas Kyte here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245